# WebGL 3D perspective

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, perspectivecamera

I'm new to WebGL and I'm following the WebGL tutorial in https://webglfundamentals.org/. I draw a 3d cube in my canvas and It worked correct.

Then I tried 3D perspective from [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective.html). After that my cube stretched and it looks like this. (I used `gl-matrix` to do matrix calculations)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

const vsSource = `
    attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec4 aColour;

    uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;
    uniform vec2 uResolution;
    uniform float uFudgeFactor;
    varying vec4 vColour;

    void main() {
        vec4 position = uModelViewMatrix * uProjectionMatrix * aVertexPosition;
        vec4 zeroToOne = position / vec4(uResolution, uResolution.x, 1);
        vec4 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
        vec4 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

        float zToDivideBy = 1.0 + clipSpace.z * uFudgeFactor;

        gl_Position = vec4(vec3(clipSpace.xy / zToDivideBy , clipSpace.z) * vec3(1, -1, 1), clipSpace.w);
        vColour = aColour;
    }
`
const fsSource = `
    precision mediump float;
    varying vec4 vColour;

    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vColour;
    }
`

const program = initShaderProgram(vsSource, fsSource)
const programInfo = {
  program: program,
  attribLocations: {
    vertexPosition: gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aVertexPosition"),
    color: gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aColour")
  },
  uniformLocations: {
    modelViewMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uModelViewMatrix"),
    projectionMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uProjectionMatrix"),
    resolution: gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uResolution"),
    fudgeFactor: gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uFudgeFactor")
  }
}

const model = mat4.create()
mat4.translate(model, model, [400, 200, 400])
const projectionMatrix = mat4.create()
mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, Math.PI / 3, 2, 1, 1000)
let buffers = initBuffers();

requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);

function drawScene() {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
  gl.clearDepth(1)
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL)

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program)

  {
    const numComponents = 3;
    const type = gl.FLOAT
    const normalize = false
    const stride = 0
    const offset = 0
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.position)
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition)
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition, numComponents, type, normalize, stride, offset)
    draw3DBox(0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100)
  }

  {
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.color)
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfo.attribLocations.color)
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(programInfo.attribLocations.color, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
    setColours()
  }

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(programInfo.uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix, false, model)
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(programInfo.uniformLocations.projectionMatrix, false, projectionMatrix)
  gl.uniform2f(programInfo.uniformLocations.resolution, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  gl.uniform1f(programInfo.uniformLocations.fudgeFactor, 0.4)
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 24)

  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene)
}

function initShaderProgram(vsSource, fsSource) {
  const vertexShader = loadShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource)
  const fragmentShader = loadShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource)

  const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram()
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader)
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader)
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram)

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    console.log("Unable to initialize the shader program >> ", gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram))
    return null
  }
  return shaderProgram
}

function loadShader(type, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type)
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source)
  gl.compileShader(shader)

  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    console.log("[ERROR] error occoured while compiling the shaders >> " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader))
    gl.deleteShader(shader)
    return null
  }
  return shader
}

function initBuffers() {
  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer()
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer)
  const colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer()
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer)

  return {
    color: colorBuffer,
    position: positionBuffer
  }
}

function draw3DBox(x, y, z, width, height, depth) {
  const positions = new Float32Array([
    // front
    x - width / 2, y - height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y - height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y + height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y + height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    // right
    x + width / 2, y + height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y - height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y + height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y - height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    // back
    x + width / 2, y - height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y - height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y + height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y + height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    // bottom
    x + width / 2, y + height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y + height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y + height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y + height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    // left
    x - width / 2, y + height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y + height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y - height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y - height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    // top
    x - width / 2, y - height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y - height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y - height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y - height / 2, z + depth / 2,
  ]);

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
}

function setColours() {
  const colours = [
    // front
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    // right
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    // back
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    // bottom
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    // left
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    // top
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 1,
  ]

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colours), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
}
```

```html
<canvas width="800px" height="400px"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
```

How can I fix this issue? Are there anything I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: any reason you didn't just follow those same tutorials to get to [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shader code is incorrect for perspective.

Here is what you have

```
    vec4 position = uModelViewMatrix * uProjectionMatrix * aVertexPosition;
    vec4 zeroToOne = position / vec4(uResolution, uResolution.x, 1);
    vec4 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
    vec4 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

    float zToDivideBy = 1.0 + clipSpace.z * uFudgeFactor;

    gl_Position = vec4(vec3(clipSpace.xy / zToDivideBy , clipSpace.z) * vec3(1, -1, 1), clipSpace.w);
```

this is what you need.

```
    gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * aVertexPosition;
```

You said you started from [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective.html) but none of that `zeroToOne` or `u_resolution` stuff is on that page. In fact resulting shader on that page is just

```
    gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
```

I also moved the cube to be in the center in front of the camera. It was behind the camera. Camera's look down -Z by default

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

const vsSource = `
    attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec4 aColour;

    uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;
    uniform vec2 uResolution;
    uniform float uFudgeFactor;
    varying vec4 vColour;

    void main() {
        gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix  * aVertexPosition;
        vColour = aColour;
    }
`
const fsSource = `
    precision mediump float;
    varying vec4 vColour;

    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vColour;
    }
`

const program = initShaderProgram(vsSource, fsSource)
const programInfo = {
  program: program,
  attribLocations: {
    vertexPosition: gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aVertexPosition"),
    color: gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aColour")
  },
  uniformLocations: {
    modelViewMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uModelViewMatrix"),
    projectionMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uProjectionMatrix"),
  }
}

const model = mat4.create()
mat4.translate(model, model, [0, 0, -400])
const projectionMatrix = mat4.create()
mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, Math.PI / 3, 2, 1, 1000)
let buffers = initBuffers();

requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);

function drawScene() {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
  gl.clearDepth(1)
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL)

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program)

  {
    const numComponents = 3;
    const type = gl.FLOAT
    const normalize = false
    const stride = 0
    const offset = 0
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.position)
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition)
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition, numComponents, type, normalize, stride, offset)
    draw3DBox(0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100)
  }

  {
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.color)
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfo.attribLocations.color)
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(programInfo.attribLocations.color, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
    setColours()
  }

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(programInfo.uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix, false, model)
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(programInfo.uniformLocations.projectionMatrix, false, projectionMatrix)
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 24)

  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene)
}

function initShaderProgram(vsSource, fsSource) {
  const vertexShader = loadShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource)
  const fragmentShader = loadShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource)

  const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram()
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader)
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader)
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram)

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    console.log("Unable to initialize the shader program >> ", gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram))
    return null
  }
  return shaderProgram
}

function loadShader(type, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type)
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source)
  gl.compileShader(shader)

  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    console.log("[ERROR] error occoured while compiling the shaders >> " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader))
    gl.deleteShader(shader)
    return null
  }
  return shader
}

function initBuffers() {
  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer()
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer)
  const colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer()
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer)

  return {
    color: colorBuffer,
    position: positionBuffer
  }
}

function draw3DBox(x, y, z, width, height, depth) {
  const positions = new Float32Array([
    // front
    x - width / 2, y - height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y - height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y + height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y + height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    // right
    x + width / 2, y + height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y - height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y + height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y - height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    // back
    x + width / 2, y - height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y - height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y + height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y + height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    // bottom
    x + width / 2, y + height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y + height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y + height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y + height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    // left
    x - width / 2, y + height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y + height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y - height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y - height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    // top
    x - width / 2, y - height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y - height / 2, z - depth / 2,
    x - width / 2, y - height / 2, z + depth / 2,
    x + width / 2, y - height / 2, z + depth / 2,
  ]);

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
}

function setColours() {
  const colours = [
    // front
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    // right
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    // back
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    // bottom
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    // left
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1,
    // top
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 1,
  ]

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colours), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
}
```

```html
<canvas width="800px" height="400px"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
</script>
```

Comment: I added that `zeroToOne` and `u_resolution stuff` from the same tutorial serious: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html

Comment: Yes, that is from the first article. It's called learning. You start simple and build up, replacing parts as you go. It sounds like maybe you didn't actually read the articles and just skimmed? The whole point of [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-camera.html) and the 7 before it (the previous one linked at the top of each article) is to show you how simple each concept is and how all of it is replaced by matrix math. But if you don't actually read it and just copy and paste code then you can't expect things to work.

Comment: I have a question. In your answer say `draw3DBox(0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100)` and you didn't change the pixel values to clip space values. But it's still working. how is it possible?

Comment: the projection matrix changes it to clip space vales as explained in those articles. [This one](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) explains you can do all that math in a single matrix, [This one](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-orthographic.html) takes it from 2D to 3D, and [this one](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective.html) adds perspective.